# Find a smooth path along which a given function on the plane is not differentiable at the origin

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

From Bamberg & Sternberg’s *A Course In Mathematics For Students of Physics*, Exercise 6.1d:

> Let $F(x,y) = \frac{x^3y}{x^2+y^2}$ for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ and
>   $F(0,0)=0$. Invent a smooth curve $x=X(t)$, $y=Y(t)$ through the
>   origin with $X(0)=Y(0)=0$, such that the function $G(t)=F(X(t),Y(t))$
>   is *not* differentiable at the origin.

I don’t think this is possible. $F$ is differentiable at the origin with $\mathrm dF_{(0,0)}=\mathbf 0$, I believe. (Converting to polar coordinates gives $F$ as $r^2$ times a bounded function, hence $o(r)$). The Chain Rule tells me that $F\circ \gamma$ for any smooth (i.e., differentiable) $\gamma(t)$ is also differentiable, so there can’t be a smooth curve that satisfies the problem’s conditions. What am I missing, if anything?

Comment: I think there is a typo in the definition of $F$. Note that the given $F$ is even $C^1$ at the origin.

Comment: That’s what I suspect, too. Not surprising, given the number of other typos I’ve found in the book thus far. I’ll try fiddling with the exponents in the definition of $F$ to get a function that works. It’ll also have to have unequal mixed partial derivatives at the origin to satisfy the other parts of the exercise.

Comment: I've encountered a similar problem but $F$ was $\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}$, all directional derivatives exists at the origin but the function is not differentiable.

Comment: Thanks, but that one won’t quite work for the rest of the exercise: the mixed partials are equal, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this exercise in the textbook has a typo somewhere, as I suspected.